# Azure DevOps: yaml build pipeline steps are skipped when pipeline runs?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I have a build pipeline in Azure DevOps whose job steps are getting skipped when the pipeline executes.  As a result, no artifacts are created and thus the subsequent release pipeline fails.  Here is my pipeline's yaml (anonymized to protect my company):

```
parameters:
 - name: buildConfig
   displayName: Build Configuration to Use
   default: Debug
   values:
    - Debug
    - Release

trigger:
  branches:
    include:
     - '*'
    exclude:
     - 'main'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: ${{ parameters.buildConfig }}
  # Azure Resource Manager connection created during pipeline creation
  azureSubscription: 'MyAzureSubscription'

  # Function app name
  functionAppName: 'MyFunction'

  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'windows-latest'

  # Working Directory
  workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/MySolution'
  testingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/MySolution.UnitTests'

stages:
  - stage: Build
    displayName: Build Stage
    jobs:
     - job: Build
       displayName: Build
       pool:
        vmImage: $(vmImageName)
  
        steps:
        - task: UseDotNet@2
          displayName: Setup Net Core 3.1.x
          inputs:
            packageType: 'sdk'
            version: '3.1.x'

        - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
          displayName: Restore Nuget Packages
          inputs:
            command: restore
            projects: '**/*.csproj'
            feedsToUse: 'select'
            vstsFeed: 'xxxxxx'
            includeNuGetOrg: true

        - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
          displayName: Build the Assembly
          inputs:
            command: 'build'
            projects: $(workingDirectory)/*.csproj
            arguments: '--output $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/publish_output --configuration $(BuildConfiguration)'

        - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
          displayName: Run Unit Tests
          inputs:
            command: 'test'
            projects: $(testingDirectory)/*.csproj
            enabled: false

        - task: ArchiveFiles@2
          displayName: 'Archive files'
          inputs:
          rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/publish_output'
          includeRootFolder: false
          archiveType: zip
          archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
          replaceExistingArchive: true

        - publish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
          artifact: drop
```

As you can see in this image, when the pipeline runs, most of the pipeline's tasks are being skipped (or are unrecognized by the yaml parser):
[image]

So when my release pipeline runs, which is defined in textbook-perfect fashion like so:
[image]

I (naturally) get this error:

```
2022-11-01T23:54:31.6148895Z ##[section]Starting: Deploy Azure Function App
2022-11-01T23:54:31.7167183Z ==============================================================================
2022-11-01T23:54:31.7168124Z Task         : Azure Functions
2022-11-01T23:54:31.7168797Z Description  : Update a function app with .NET, Python, JavaScript, PowerShell, Java based web applications
2022-11-01T23:54:31.7169159Z Version      : 1.211.1
2022-11-01T23:54:31.7169691Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2022-11-01T23:54:31.7170251Z Help         : https://aka.ms/azurefunctiontroubleshooting
2022-11-01T23:54:31.7170636Z ==============================================================================
2022-11-01T23:54:35.3856852Z Got service connection details for Azure App Service:'MyFunctionApp'
2022-11-01T23:54:35.7752025Z ##[error]Error: No package found with specified pattern: D:\a\r1\a\**\*.zip<br/>Check if the package mentioned in the task is published as an artifact in the build or a previous stage and downloaded in the current job.
2022-11-01T23:54:35.7842428Z ##[section]Finishing: Deploy Azure Function App
```

What am I doing wrong?  Is my YAML syntax invalid, even though I successfully validated it with an online YAML linter?  In addition, I copied this YAML nearly word-for-word from a working pipeline.  Any suggestions?

Comment: The screenshot would indicate that the pipeline contains no steps at all. Are you *sure* you're working out of the correct YAML file?

Answer (score 1):

Your pasted yaml is not structurally valid; see for example the "steps" which is indented underneath "pool":

[image: yaml code from question]

I am not sure if this is a mistake as it was pasted into the question, or if your yaml file is genuinely indented like that.

Comment: I would expect an indentation error to give a syntax error and not run, not simply skip the steps. But this is a good catch nonetheless.